# Convergence of the real part of the integral associated with a characteristic function

Tags: analysis, characteristic-functions

Let  $I_n (t) = \int (e^{itu} -1)\frac{1+ u^2}{u^2}\, dG_n(u)$ be such that 
$$
I_n(t) \to \log f(t)
$$

where $f(t)$ is the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible law.

Why is it that $$ \Re I_n(t) \to \log |f(t)|\;\;\;?$$

This is taken from Kolmogorov's book:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex numbers, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) $\log z = \log |z| + i \arg z$. Consequently, since $I_n(t) \to \log f(t) = \log |f(t)| + i \arg f(t)$, where only the first term is real, $\Re I_n(t) \to \log |f(t)|$.